# Tool for nucleotide alignment with all nucleotide codes (e.g. R, Y, W, S, etc.)?

Tags: dna, bioinformatics, dna-sequencing, nucleic-acids, sequence-analysis

I have a vector sequence and would like to find the following nucleotide sequence in it.

```
AASYWSRA
```

This query sequence uses several degenerate symbols, defined as:

- S = C or G (**S**trong)
- Y = C or T (p**Y**rimidine)
- W = A or T (**W**eak)
- R = A or G (pu**R**ine)

(See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleotide#Abbreviation_codes_for_degenerate_bases) for a complete description of the IUPAC nucleotide codes.)

Is there a tool to align this sequence with the vector and find all the possible sites?

EDIT: I found [this website](http://www.expasy.org/genomics/sequence_alignment) but couldn't find any of the resources helpful. Maybe one of these will work but I found most of them too complicated. If you know which one will work and explain how to use it I will be grateful.

Comment: I could've sworn NCBI BLAST can do that? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an exact match, you don't really need a complex aligner. Perl regular expressions are pretty powerful at string transformations or conditional matching of substrings. For example, to find all matches of `AASYWSRA` in a nucleotide sequence `$seq`, you can do:

```
@matches = $seq =~ m/AA[CG][CT][AT][CG][AG]A/g;
```

The `[]` brackets are known as Perl character classes, which allow different characters in a position.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [MAST](http://meme.nbcr.net/meme/cgi-bin/mast.cgi) to search for particular motifs in a sequence.

From the [MAST intro page](http://meme.nbcr.net/meme/mast-intro.html), it looks like you'll have to reformat your motif a little, but it should suffice for your purposes:

> Motifs are represented as position-dependent scoring matrices that
>   describe the score of each possible letter at each position in the
>   pattern.

[Here is more info on formatting](http://www.cbil.upenn.edu/EpoDB/release/version_2.2/meme/motif-format.html), which also indicates that the alphabet you use will be interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've never utilized the feature, but I know [Vmatch](http://www.vmatch.de/) allows you to define your own alphabets and symbol mappings, which should allow you to handle the IUPAC ambiguous nucleotide symbols. The default alphabet/mapping may even include these symbols.

Comment: Unfortunately, vmatch treats the letters in symbol mappings as equivalent (e.g. S = C). It does not handle that S can be C or G. The symbol mapping is intended for handling case (e.g. t = T) or to group similar amino acids.